# Cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, require

**Angular 1.5.11**

I migrate an app from RequireJS 2.2 to Webpack 3.5.5 + ES6 modules. During bundle creation there is an error:

```
ERROR in ./app/services/routeResolver.js
Cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)' in line 175
 @ ./app/app.module.js 33:0-34
 @ ./app/app.js
```

And I have the following function in this routeResolver service:

```
        ...
        var resolveDependencies = function ($q, $rootScope, dependencies) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var loader = new Loader();

            require(dependencies, function () {
                defer.resolve();
                $rootScope.$apply()
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }; 
        ...
```

The `dependencies` argument is an array which contains a path to controller, for example `app/controllers/nameOfController.js`. The function resolves controller asynchronously.

How to substitute this `require` with ES6 syntax? Or maybe there is an external module to do it?

**app.js**

```
import './app.module';
import './app.config';
import './app.run';
import './controllers/firstController'
import './directives/firstDirective'
...
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

**app.module.js**

```
import 'angular';
...
import './services/routeResolver';
...
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'routeResolver',
  ...
]);
export default app;
```

**app/services/routeResolver.js**

```
var routeResolver = function () {
...
};
var moduleName = 'routeResolver';
angular.module(moduleName, []).provider(moduleName, routeResolver);
export default moduleName;
```

**app/controllers/firstController.js**

```
var injectParams = ['$scope', 'myEvents'];
var FirstController = function ($scope, myEvents) {
...
};
FirstController.$inject = injectParams;
var moduleName = 'firstController';
angular.module(moduleName, []).provider(moduleName, FirstController);
export default moduleName;
```

Comment: Unless there's a considerable bandwidth benefit, lazy loading doesn't pay off.  Just make a monolithic bundle. The alternative is `import()`, and it will  fail too. Because Webpack needs to know which module exactly should be bundled in order to use it in bundled app. The restrictions are the same as for `require`. See https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-

Comment: hi @srgbnd, did you get the solution for this problem?